# How to create a Checkbox and access global variable from class?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a  checkbox inside my view. I declared bool variable isChecked= false in my state class, and while writing constructor for checkbox getting the error on my isChecked variable as 'Only static members can be accessed in intializers'. I made the variable as static, which removed the error on bool variable, but giving the same error on setState(). How do i resolve this ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Card Screen',
      home: new myPetScreen()
    );
  }
}


class myPetScreen extends StatefulWidget{

  myPetScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;



  @override
  _myPetScreenState createState() => new _myPetScreenState();
}

class _myPetScreenState extends State<myPetScreen>{

   static bool isChecked = false;

  final view = new Column(

    children: <Widget>[
      //did other UI Implementation here 
      Container(

        child: Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, position){

            return Card( 
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(position.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),),
                      Spacer(),
                      Checkbox(
                       value: isChecked,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                       setState(() {
                          isChecked = value;
                        });
                     },
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                )
            );
          }
          ),
        ),

      ) ,

    ],
  );

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Card Screen')),
      body: view,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're gonna have to share with us how you're implementing this code inside your stateful widget. And what do you mean by view?

Comment: Thanks @HassanSaleh, I have edited my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make some change take your column code into one method then that method called into widget..
like this way..

```
Column getView(){
var view = new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    //did other UI Implementation here
    Container(
      child: Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      position.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Checkbox(
                      value: isChecked,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        changeState(value);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        }),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
return view;
}
```

after that called this way..

```
 body: getView()
```

Comment: My bad.... didn't post the entire code. I had done that only, still its showing an error.  Have edited it now!

Comment: Thankyou so much! I understood my mistake..its working now

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring view as a final variable, so it is immutable. change it to a function like so:

```
Widget get view => Container(
   //...
)
```

Also, don't forget to remove static from the state declaration (Never do that in a stateful wiget).